# How to repeat height and width change automatically when div is scrolled into view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I change the `height` and the `width` of my `div` automatically and frequently when my `div` is scrolled into view?

**HTML**

```
<div id="contact" class="fadeInBlock">
    <div class="map">
        <div class="pointer">
            <div class="dot"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="address">
            <address></address>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

(The `div` who's going to change `height` and `width` is the `.pointer`).

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('.pointer').css({"width": "60px", "height": "60px"});
    });
});
```

I've only done the change `width` and `height` part, if I wasn't clear enough, please tell me and I will do my best to clear your confusion.

Comment: Check `offset()` and `scrollTop()` functions.

Comment: How often do you want to change it? And, how do you want to change it?

Comment: @mpactMEDIA Every 7 seconds, like a drop of water if you know what I mean.

Comment: You want it to ripple out and in?

Comment: @mpactMEDIA Any idea of how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('.pointer').css({'height':($(window).height())+'px'});
    });
});
```

Comment: Would be good if you explained what changes you made and why this works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to bounce the width and height. I would store the animation points and loop through the animate function multiple times.

Some other people here gave you strategies for the scroll event but you asked for the bouncing effect too.

Hope this helps,
Tim

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("div").animate({
            opacity: '0.5',
            height: '150px',
            width: '150px'
        });
        $("div").animate({
            opacity: '0.5',
            height: '50px',
            width: '50px'
        });
        $("div").animate({
            opacity: '0.5',
            height: '100px',
            width: '100px'
        });
        $("div").animate({
            opacity: '0.5',
            height: '75px',
            width: '75px'
        });
        $("div").animate({
            opacity: '0.5',
            height: '200px',
            width: '200px'
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Start Animation</button>
<div style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;"></div>
```